# YOLOv3 darknet detector test works on individual images, but cannot load multiple images from txt file

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet

```
!./darknet detector test data/yolov3_proj-13.data cfg/yolov3_5l_proj_Testing.cfg  /content/drive/MyDrive/darknet/backup/Project/yolov3_5l_proj_best_416_mAP3069.weights -dont_show < /content/drive/MyDrive/darknet/valid_proj_yolov3.txt > /content/drive/MyDrive/darknet/backup/Project/result.txt # -ext_output
```

When I run the above command to test my trained YOLOv3 network on multiple test images in a .txt file, I get the "Cannot load image" error on all the image paths in the file:
[image]

The image paths in the .txt file are correct, and they work perfectly when I run 'darknet detect' on individual images.

Could you help me in getting the detector command works correctly on multiple test images?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at the following link:
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/611#issuecomment-401942856

"Make sure that the end of line sequences are "/n" and not "/r/n". In a text editor (like visual studio code) make sure you have LF and not CRLF and also that the file format is UTF8."

So, using Visual Studio Code, I edited the "valid_proj_yolov3.txt" file (which has the paths to the test images) to have LF instead of CRLF in the last line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer.